# GEOS C++ geos::Geometry Buffer(0) false assertion on convexHull

Tags: c++, geos

I'm currently using the C++ GEOS API to iterate over a `vector` of typedef `Points` (x and y member variables).

I turn this vector into a convexHull by creating a `geos::geom::Geometry` object, buffering at 0 to prevent self intersections, and then creating a convex Hull.

Whenever I send an object that is already a convexHull, I get the following assertion: `Assertion 'precisionModel' failed`.

Is this a GEOS bug? Do I need to be careful not to buffer on a convex polygon?

**geo_algos_test2: /tmp/libgeos/src/operation/buffer/BufferBuilder.cpp:373: geos::geom::Geometry* geos::operation::buffer::BufferBuilder::buffer(const geos::geom::Geometry*, double): Assertion `precisionModel' failed.***

Here is my code:

```
// Remove self intersections or collinear points

geos::geom::GeometryFactory factory;
geos::geom::CoordinateSequence* temp =
    factory.getCoordinateSequenceFactory()->create((std::size_t)0, 0);

// Convert vector of cruise points to GEOS
for (auto point : poly) {
    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(point.x, point.y));
}
// Add beggining point to create linear ring
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(poly.begin()->x, poly.begin()->y));

// Create Linear Ring For Constructor
geos::geom::LinearRing* box = factory.createLinearRing(temp);
// Factory returns a pointer, dereference this
geos::geom::Geometry* GEOSPoly = factory.createPolygon(box, NULL);

// Remove Self Intersections and create Hull
return GEOSPoly->buffer(0); //line that causes assertion
```

Comment: An assertion is not a segmentation fault.  An assertion is a check placed into the code to see if some condition has been met before proceeding, and the check failed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an assertion. Its a check in their internal library that fails

Answer (score 1):

The assertion indicates that your `factory` and/or the `box` geometry does not have any instance of `PrecisionModel` attached.

In the current GEOS C++ API, the default constractor is not accessible and you create factory this way:

```
auto factory = geos::geom::GeometryFactory::create()
```

Now, `factory` uses default float-point precision model and `factory->getPrecisionModel()` must be non-`nullptr`.

Any geometry instance created with `geos::geom::GeometryFactory::create*` functions family receives the factory's precision model, namely, `box->getPrecisionModel()` returns pointer to the same instance of `PrecisionModel` class.